# Compute the following line integral: $\oint_C \frac{\text{d}x}{y} -\frac{\text{d}y}{x}$ Where $C$ is the circle $x^2+y^2=1$.

Tags: partial-derivative, line-integrals, greens-theorem

Compute the following line integral:
$$\oint_C \frac{\text{d}x}{y} -\frac{\text{d}y}{x}$$

Where $C$ is the circle $x^2+y^2=1$.

---

The function $1/y$ and it's first partial derivative with respective to $y$ are not defined on the points lying in the $x$ axis, and the function $-1/x$ and it's first partial derivative with respective to $x$ are not defined on the points lying in the $y$ axis, so we can't use Green's theorem, so how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:**

On $C$, parameterize $(x,y)$ as $(\cos(\phi),\sin(\phi))$ with $\phi \in [-\pi,\pi]$.

Can you finish now?

Comment: If we know that $x=\cos(\phi)$ and $y=\sin(\phi)$, then what are the differentials $dx$ and $dy$?  Do you have it now?

Comment: Well I guess the integral is: $$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{-\sin\left(\theta\right)}{\sin\left(\theta\right)}-\frac{\cos\left(\theta\right)}{\cos\left(\theta\right)} d \theta=-4\pi$$

Comment: You are correct!  Well done.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  Green's Theorem does not apply since on the disk $x^2+y^2\le 1$,  $\frac1x$ and $\frac1y$ are not continuously differentiable.

Comment: @masaheb I've posted a solution for the problem you referenced.